# How do I carve a Trench in a terrain with a curved array object non destructively

Tags: shrinkwrap

I want a very editable/non destructive way to create a trench on a terrain. Below is a mesh I created using the paths tool. I want to apply the shape to the terrain. I tried using shrinkwrap on the terrain but it create very jagged results.

shrinkwrap attempt

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you made the ground surface into a solid block (select the face and extrude down), and enclosed the top and end of your canyon, then you could make the canyon a boolean object.

That is - put the canyon where you want it to be, then select the ground layer, add a boolean modifier and select the canyon as the target object.  Then you hide the canyon object.

Comment: My trench is arrayed down a curve. When I enclose the shape, the boolean operation doesn't work because there are ends on each array instance.